# A question about complement of a closed subspace of a Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be  a Banach space and $M$ be a closed subspace of $X$. Suppose that there exists a subspace $N$ of $X$ such that $X=M\oplus N$. Does it imply that $N$ is closed ?

I know that not every closed subspace of a Banach space is complemented (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108284/example-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space-which-is-not-complemented)). But my question is slightly different from that question. I think the answer is no. But I do not able to construct a counter example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Writing $X = M \oplus N$ implies that the projection $\pi_1: X \to M$ is continuous.  Then $N = \pi^{-1}(\{0\})$ must be closed.

Comment: Without assuming that $N$ is closed, how to prove that $\pi_1$ is continuous?

Comment: It's usually part of the definition of $\oplus$ in Banach spaces.

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Can you elaborate on how to see that the projection is continuous, please? *(If it were not by definition.)*

Comment: How do **you** want to define $X = M \oplus N$?

Comment: Apologies for being pedantic 2 years on, but the general categorical definition of an (external) direct sum $M \oplus N$ of $M$ and $N$ is given in terms of injections from $M$ and $N$ to $M \oplus N$ and not in terms of projections from $M \oplus N$ to $M$ and $N$ (these arise in the definition of products). The definitions of an internal direct sum for Banach spaces that I know of don't mention projections (why would they?), but just say that it is a vector space internal direct sum whose summands are sub-Banach spaces (i.e., closed).

Comment: Hmm, you seem to be right. The definition of $M \oplus N$ in Rudin, "Functional Analysis" is indeed that way.

Comment: @RobArthan: The categorical definition of a direct sum in a additive (or preadditive) category is usually (and originally!) given in terms of a pair of morphisms, $\pi_i:M_1\oplus M_2\to M_i$, called "projections", as well as a pair of morphisms, $\iota_i:M_i\to M_1\oplus M_2$, called "injections", for $i=1,2$, respectively, that satisfy the direct sum relations $\iota_1\pi_1+\iota_2\pi_2=\operatorname{id}_{M_1\oplus M_2}$ as well as $\pi_i\iota_i=\operatorname{id}_i$ for $i=1,2$.

Comment: For a reference see "Mac Lane, Categories for the Working Mathematician, chapter IIIV, section 2, Additive Categories".

Comment: @RobertIsrael: I just noticed that I answered my question in the comment, upsi.. ^^ By the way, nice answer! (+1)

Answer (score 4):

I think the question you are trying to get at is about the relation between algebraic complements and topological complements ie if

1) M and N are complemented algebraically (complements defined without any topology involved).

2) M is closed.

Does this mean N is closed?

The answer is no,  See this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454408/algebraic-and-topological-complements-in-a-hilbert-space) on the same site for a counterexample.

See this [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0501048) for more relations between algebraic and topological complements. In the Banach space setting, two closed subspaces are algebraic complemented if and only if they are topologically complemented.