# If $M\oplus N=B$ is a Banach space and $M$ is closed, does that imply that $N$ is closed as well?

Tags: functional-analysis

I am aware a similar question had been answered before on the site, see([A question about complement of a closed subspace of a Banach space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1154873/a-question-about-complement-of-a-closed-subspace-of-a-banach-space)).
I find the answer given there unsatisfying since it relies on a categorical definition of direct sum where as my definition is strictly algebraic.

In my book the notion of a direct sum simply asserts a unique presentation of any element in $B$ as a sum of an element in $M$ and an element in $N$ (both of which are linear sub-spaces of $B$). In that case is it still true that $N$ has to be closed?

Comment: Just to clarify, by $M\oplus N=B$ you mean that $M$ and $N$ are subspaces of $B$, $M+N=B$, and $M\cap N=\{0\}$?

Comment: If you're using the purely algebraic notion of direct sum, then "no". Let $N$ be any non-closed subspace of finite codimension. But the purely algebraic notion is not well-suited in functional analysis.

Comment: could you give a specific example of a non-closed subspace of finite co-dimension?